# Is it ok to pass an int array to scanf and printf when using the %s specifier?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, language-lawyer

I stumbled upon a question with this code

```
int arr[10];
scanf("%s", arr);
printf("%s", arr);
```

I don't know the purpose, and I'm perfectly aware of how much this code smells. But my question here is if this i legal, and if I can expect it to reprint the string I enter? (Provided that the input string isn't so long that it causes buffer overflow)

And I also wonder if there's any example where this is actually useful.

From the C standard about fprintf https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8

> If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.

and fscanf https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12

> If no l length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically.

And in this case, it's not a character array. But I seem to recall that there are some special rules about implicit conversions to and from char pointers, but I also have a memory that these does not apply to variadic functions.

Comment: It's formally UB but in case scanf just converts the pointer to a `char*` (and the standard lib gets compiled as standard C, which is by no means required), then it will work.

Comment: It can be made legal by using `(char *)arr` in the `scanf` and `printf` parameters. But note that `scanf` may then set the `int` elements of `arr` to trap representations, which might result in an implementation-defined signal being raised when reading the `int` elements.

Comment: @TomKarzes You're probably the first programmer in the entire history that makes that mistake ;)

Answer (score 5):

For the language lawyer I would say it is illegal:

From C11: 7.21.6.

> `s`     If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be **a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type**. 280)

and

> 9     If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. 282) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

For any practical use I would say that I cannot think of a scenario where it might fail as long as you don't enter more characters than fit into the array.

Update after question was extended:

> But I seem to recall that there are some special rules about implicit conversions to and from char pointers, but I also have a memory that these does not apply to variadic functions.

Correct, implicit conversions can only happen if type of destination is known. For variadic functions no such conversion is done for pointers.

And also in those cases where an implicit conversion would be done, it is only possible if one of them is `void *`, not between `int *` and `char *`.

Answer (score 2):

> ... that there are some special rules about implicit conversions to and from char pointers

No, that's not correct.

For void pointers you have implicit conversion but not for char pointers. In the very old K&R days (i.e. before "void" was introduced) char pointers were used as "the generic pointer" type but still there was no implicit conversion.

Maybe you are confusing conversion with aliasing. For aliasing char pointers are special as a char pointer is allowed to alias other object types.

The conclusion is that the code has undefined behavior. Passing an int pointer when a char pointer is expected is not standard compliant.

Comment: *"Maybe you are confusing conversion with aliasing"* - Yep. For some reason I'm always mixing this up

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to access an `int` or an array of `int` using `char` references; C 2018 6.5 7 says character types may be used to access an object.

However, for `%s`, `scanf` and `printf` should be passed a `char *`, not an `int *`. Even though a `char *` may be used (with dereferencing) to access an `int` or array of `int`, that does not mean an `int *` will serve in place of a `char *`. When `scanf` or `printf` attempts to get the `char *` they expect (as by using `va_arg`), the fact that an `int *` was passed makes the behavior not defined by the C standard.

If instead you convert the `int *` to a `char *`:

```
scanf("%s", (char *) arr);
printf("%s", (char *) arr);
```

then the behavior is arguably defined by the C standard. (“Arguably” because the internals of `scanf` and `printf` are not formally specified. Presumably they align with the aliasing rules in 6.5 7.)

Answer (score -2):

The program will run but with a warning explaining that `%s` expects the variable `arr` to be a `char *` type otherwise an array of `char`.
So, the output will be the string that the user types on demand of the program...

Comment: I cannot see how this answers if it's legal or not

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).